# Where are the java.net.HttpURLConnection default timeouts documented?

Tags: java

The [java.net.HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class allows you to set a connect timeout and a read timeout. However, the Javadoc page does not specify what the values of the read and connection timeouts are if you do not specify them.

Are the default connect and read timeouts documented anywhere? I was able to determine them empirically by writing a simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(String.format("connection timeout: %d", conn.getConnectTimeout()));
        System.out.println(String.format("read timeout: %d", conn.getReadTimeout()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

(On MacOS and Linux, for the version of Java 1.8 I was running these were both `0`, meaning no timeout).

However, what I would really like is a URL with official documentation on this.

Comment: It is possible that the lack of documentation means that the canonical answer is "the defaults are undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpUrlConnection` inherits the timeout fields and getter/setter methods from `UrlConnection`

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/net/URLConnection.java

```
/**

 * @since 1.5

 */

private int connectTimeout;
private int readTimeout;
```

Since they are never assigned another value on declaration, they are 0. The document explicitly mentions that non-standard implementations may choose to entirely ignore the timeout variables and define their own implementation or fields or static values.

[Sun's implementation of HttpURLConnection does this.](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java)

```
/* Redefine timeouts from java.net.URLConnection as we need -1 to mean
 * not set. This is to ensure backward compatibility.
 */
private int connectTimeout = NetworkClient.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT;
private int readTimeout = NetworkClient.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT;
```